# Batch script to loop over files while renaming them

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, directory

I can use this to loop over files:

```
for %%a in ("%directory%\*.%extension%") do (
    echo FILE: %%~fa
)
goto :eof
```

What if I also rename the files, like this (`:rename` is a subroutine that renames the files):

```
for %%a in ("%directory%\*.%extension%") do (
    echo FILE: %%~fa
    call :rename "%%~fa"
)
goto :eof
```

In that case, some of the files are renamed (and echoed) two or even three times. I think it's because after they are renamed, in some cases they are regarded as new files that also need to be looped through. However, this does not happen with all the renamed files.

How can I overcome this? I want every file to be renamed only once.

**Solution:**

```
:: remove quotes:
:: http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.TrimQuotes

for /f "useback tokens=*" %%a in ('%extension%') do set extension=%%~a

for /f "useback tokens=*" %%a in ('%directory%') do set directory=%%~a

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d "%directory%\*.%extension%" ^| sort /r') do (
    echo FILE: %directory%\%%a
    call :renamingSubroutine "%directory%\%%a"
)
goto :eof
```

OR:

```
:: remove quotes:
:: http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.TrimQuotes

for /f "useback tokens=*" %%a in ('%extension%') do set extension=%%~a

for /f "useback tokens=*" %%a in ('%directory%') do set directory=%%~a

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s /on "%directory%\*.%extension%"') do (
    echo FILE: %%~fa
    call :renamingSubroutine "%%~fa"
)
goto :eof
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /a-d /s "%directory%\*.%extension%"^|sort /r') do (
    echo FILE: %%~fa
    call :rename "%%~fa"
)
goto :eof
```

BTW you shouldn't give batch functions the names of cmd commands (`rename`).

Comment: Thanks.. I actually didn't call it `rename` in actual code, but thanks for mentioning this. I think what prevents your code from fully working is that I want the `dir` to output full path as well, otherwise `%%a` takes the path of batch file (which is wrong). I tried changing the switch `/a-d` to `/ad` as shown here: http://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/08/how-to-generate-directory-listing-with-full-path-from-batch/ however I only suddenly got `File Not Found`...

Comment: Even in command line, if I try `dir /b /ad "J:\Temp\*.jpg"` I get `File Not Found`, but if I try `dir /b "J:\Temp\*.jpg"` files are listed... why is that?

Comment: Ok, I figured out the manual was somewhat misleading. By directories they meant subdirectories... I've updated my question above with the solution. Thanks Endoro.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's even better.